# Spring DATA JPA - Support JPA Arithmetic Functions

Tags: spring, collections, size, sql-order-by, spring-data-jpa

When you use Repository interface, you can use this implementation : PagingAndSortingRepository.

This implementation can use Sort object to generate ORDER BY request.

If I have these POJOs :

```
@Entity
public class Data{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String data;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Like> likes;

...
}

@Entity
public class Like{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String data;

...
}
```

And when I use this interface for the persistance layer by spring :

```
public interface DataRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Data, Long> {
    List<Data> findBy...(Pageable page);
}
```

So, I want to order by the number of likes. But I can't do that, because the property is a collection (when i sort by likes property, it does a sort that I do not understand).
In JPA you can use this JPQL request :

```
SELECT * FROM DATA order by SIZE(d.likes);
```

So is it possible to use this arithmetic function direcly by the sort object ?
Can I do that with the querySQL interface ?

Thx :)

Comment: Can you do `@Query("SELECT d FROM Data d ORDER BY SIZE(d.likes)") Page<Data> findAll(Pageable page)`?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a database view of aggregate data and link your Data to this view using for example @SecondaryTable and than use it in place of your original entity.